# A solution with the same name "extendeddiagnosticproviders.wsp" or id {guid} already exists in the solution store.

Tags: diagnostics, spdiag

I recently installed SharePoint 2010 and received the error message.

*IIS Is not installed, please install IIS*

But indeed, IIS was installed.  Upon running the command-line version of the config tool with verbose logging turned on, I learned it couldn't find one of the assemblies from Microsoft Chart Controls for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.

After installing the libraries, I was able to complete the install.  After using the install for a few minutes, I tried something and got a "Failed to complete action: Correlation ID" then a guid.

I've now downloaded the SharePoint diagnostic studio and I am getting this error:

*A solution with the same name "extendeddiagnosticproviders.wsp" or id {guid} already exists in the solution store.*

What have I gotten myself into? How can I make the SharePoint development experience less awful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "extendeddiagnosticproviders.wsp" gets installed part of the Administration toolkit.
Uninstalling the Administration Toolkit from the server does not retract the solution from the farm.The solution is named "extendeddiagnosticproviders.wsp" and is deployed globally to all SharePoint Web Frontend servers.

You can retract and remove the solution by going to the system settings in Central Administration, and clicking on "Manage farm solutions".

**In this case, i Guess you are trying to install the sharepoint administration kit once again in the environment.
Please provide more details about your installation process or You can check in Sharepoint ULS Logs to give us more details to solve your issue.**

Comment: Great answer! Revoking the solution did the trick.  It looks like you also have to have the SharePoint admin service running, which I didn't when I first opened the admin.  Running the diagnostics studio without the SharePoint admin service running will create the solution, then complain about it again in the process.  In short: Start sharepoint admin service, THEN run the Diagnostics studio.  The poor quality of this software is absolutely mind boggling.